# check list if it is empty or null flutter

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dart

I get this from the server, and I need to put my checkbox to true for values ​​with null, while I don't have to do anything if I find []

```
{"FRI": [null], "MON": [null], "SAT": [null], "SUN": [{"to": "16:27", "from": "15:27"}], "THU": [null], "TUE": [null], "WED": []}
```

I'm trying with a

```
if (widget.initialValues!.every((e) => e == null)) {
  _isClosed.trigger(true);
}
```

but it does not work correctly because in both cases it returns to be true

[image: UPDATE]

Answer (score 2):

when you try to use each item of an array and compare it to `null`, `[null]` and `[]` would have similar results. Instead, you should use `.isEmpty` because this method defines that is an array is empty or not, and in this approach `[null] and` []` are not equal because the first one has one element but the other one has 0 elements! For example:

```
//an example list
const list = [ [], [null]];
  
  for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    if(list[i].isEmpty){
      print("empty " + i.toString());
    } else {
      print("not empty " + i.toString());
    }
  }
```

and the result will be:

```
empty 0
not empty 1
```

Similarly, you can use `.length` as follow:

```
const list = [ [], [null]];
for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    print(i.toString() + " length is " + list[i].length.toString());
  }
```

These are only examples and you can map them to your code as well.

Comment: mm ok, the examples are pretty clear to me, but in my code if I do an if (widget.initialValues! .isEmpty) it also takes me the values ​​with the null ..

Comment: no, you should check element-wise not for entire initial values! because you want to be able to return `true` for each item that has `[null]` but in contrast do not want to have this feature for items with `[]`. so you should check whole item separately

Comment: mm ok i understand thanks, but I try to write your code but I have error.. I update my question with photo

Comment: I think you are missing something, please provide the `initialValue` so I can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

sorry if I reply to you with another account but I am at home with another pc and I do not have a user, I hope you will read ..

```
      final List<OpeningHours?>? initialValues;

class OpeningHours {
  OpeningHours({
    required this.open,
    required this.close,
  }) : assert(
          open.isBefore(close),
          "L'apertura dev'essere per forza prima della chiusura",
        );

  factory OpeningHours.fromMap(Map map) {
    if (!map.containsKey('from') || !map.containsKey('to')) {
      final msg =
          'La mappa $map non è valida per creare un oggetto [OpeningTime]';
      throw Exception(msg);
    }
    final from = TimeOfDayExtension.parse(map['from']! as String);
    final to = TimeOfDayExtension.parse(map['to']! as String);
    return OpeningHours(open: from, close: to);
  }

  final TimeOfDay open;

  final TimeOfDay close;

  String get format => '${open.asString()}-${close.asString()}';

  @override
  String toString() => jsonEncode(toMap());

  Map<String, String> toMap() =>
      {'from': open.asString(), 'to': close.asString()};
}
```